# PrimeFaces dialog keeps the previous value

Tags: java, jsf, dialog, primefaces

I use a dataTable to display the some records. The user can add/change records using a dialog named actionsDialog. Before saving the record, a modal dialog, called reasonDialog, is displayed and the user has to enter some reasons for the current operation. In my logic I set the reason to null after the data is saved into database.

The problem appears when I repeat the operation. The reason contains the previous value. I have debugged the code and noticed that this happens because the reason is assigned the local value of the inputTextarea. How can I get rid of the local value? I am using PrimeFaces 3.0, Mojara 2.0.4, Tomcat 7.

My reason dialog facelet is:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">  
    <p:dialog header="#{label.reason}" widgetVar="reasonDialog"
        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true" dynamic="true">        
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="40" autoResize="false"
                value="#{recordsBean.reason}" maxLength="1024" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:outputPanel layout="block">
                <p:commandButton value="ok" update="genericRecords msgs"
                    action="#{recordsBean.execute}"
                    oncomplete="reasonDialog.hide();actionsDialog.hide()" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

The action dialog looks like this:

```
<p:dialog id="actionsDialog" widgetVar="actionsDialog" dynamic="true"
    resizable="false" height="600" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true">
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/genericRecord.xhtml"/>
<f:facet name="footer">  
        <p:outputPanel layout="block">
    <p:commandButton value="save" onclick="reasonDialog.show()" />
    <p:commandButton value="cancel" immediate="true" 
                oncomplete="actionsDialog.hide()" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: try to assign an id to your dialog `id="reasonDialogID"` adn add add its id in the `update` attribute of that button that opens the dialog

Comment: I have added id="reasonDialogId" to the dialog and set it to the button's update attribut, but still it's not working. Beside this, the reason value is not set correctly, it is always null.

Comment: Don't you invoke some bean method in that button click ? a method in which you will set data into  `recordsBean` ? what scope is that `recordsBean` make it a view scope atleast...

Comment: When the button is clicked the execute method of recordsBean is called. The recordsBean is session scoped.

Comment: make sure you open the `reasonDialog` dialog oncomplete of that button click ? post the code of that button that opens the dialog....

Comment: not sure it will do any change but try `update=":reasonDialog"`

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried with :reasonDialog and :reasonDialogId.

Comment: b.t.w always make sure that your dialog id != your widgetVarID , its very important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add ajax="false" attribute in your p:commandButton; See sample

```
   <p:commandButton value="ok" update="genericRecords msgs"
                action="#{recordsBean.execute}" ajax="false"
                oncomplete="reasonDialog.hide();actionsDialog.hide()" />
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to update/refresh dialog's contents before showing it. Reference its (relative) client ID in the `update` attribute and move the `show()` from `onclick` to `oncomplete` so that it takes place after the update.

```html
<p:commandButton value="save" update="reasonDialog" oncomplete="reasonDialog.show()" />
```

Otherwise it will of course still display the old content as it was before it was closed. You're namely by ajax/JS interacting with exactly the same page, not a new page or so.

Comment: I have tried <p:commandButton value="save" update="reasonDialogId" oncomplete="reasonDialog.show()" /> and <p:commandButton value="save" update="reasonDialog" oncomplete="reasonDialog.show()" /> and it doesn't work.

Comment: I Have the same problem, but in a Dialog that had previous error. I think its like your article says http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html . It is still an issue in Prime 5.3 ?

Comment: Found it. In Primefaces you could use RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("your_form_id"); to reset the form values, or use the resetValues="true" in p:commandButton

Comment: @TiagoPC i have the same problem , but your solution didn't work for me , do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Try using     org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener   phase listener

Answer (score 0):

**//This is an Alternative Solution if nothing worked:**

Nothing worked for me...answers or comments.. so i had to do the following:

I used `ResetInputs` to reset the form inside my dialog and a method to open it from my bean.

So,

```
<p:commandButton value="Show" actionListener="#{myBean.showDialog()}" update=":myForm">
            <p:resetInput target=":myForm"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

And then in my bean i did this method, wich opens the dialog (with the dialog's widgetVar) and initialize my object again, so every time i open my dialog, the values in all the `<p:inputText>` (or whatever) will be always in blank/null.

```
public void showDialog(){

    car = new Car();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('wvDialog').show();");
    //added widgetVar to myDialog called wvDialog 
}
```

Inside the dialog i have some `<p:inputText>`, `<p:selectOneMenu>`, `<p:calendar>` and others. All of them dont remember previous values again when the dialog is closed, after submit, or errors.
This was the only way it worked for me, hope it helps some1!

Comment: Then it would have been better to create a new question trying to find out why it does not work for you but does for many others. It is now unclear why your solution should be choosen (and when) instead of the others. (The now 9 upvoted answer by BalusC is the way it is normally done)

Comment: You're right @Kukeltje, i should of... but i could not wait for an answer at that time..nothing worked maybe because i have several list depending of others, many update events, and more than one object since i use like 4 filters and actions... so nothing cleaned the dialog. This is like an alternative solution if needed i guess, and considering the post is a year old. I will be careful next time with my answers, im new here and loving primefaces, regards.